# Can you spawn the Wall of Flesh multiple times?

Tags: terraria

Can I spawn the Wall Of Flesh twice? I have spawned it once and I don't want to try and get another voodoo doll and not be able to use it.

Answer (score 16):

**Yes, you can spawn the Wall of Flesh twice. In fact, you can spawn it multiple times.**

I think I know your problem. After you spawn the Wall of Flesh, your Guide will be killed.

After you defeat the Wall of Flesh, you ***CANNOT*** fight it again *immediately*.

You have to wait for the Guide to come back before you kill it again to spawn the Wall of Flesh.

Take note that you need the **Voodoo Doll of the Guide** and throw it in lava, then you can spawn the **Wall of Flesh.**

Comment: The lava you throw the Guide Voodoo Doll in must be in the Underworld.( In case you didn't know.)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can kill the WoF multiple times. Its even recommended to do so as he drops emblems wich increases the DMG of certain weapon types, ex:Warrior emblem.

They are also used in crafting the "Avenger Emblem", wich is very useful.